# Absolute positioned element adds huge white spaces

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I am working on a website: https://debifit.de and everything is fine on Chrome, FF and Edge.

But in IE11 it adds huge white space at the bottom and - if you remove overflow:hidden from the body tag - also to the right.

After hours of research I found that the element causing these issues is div#stickysmartphone, as long it has position: absolute. When ScrollMagic.js sets it to fixed, the white spaces disappear.
It is also positioned more to the right than in the other browsers.

```
#stickysmartphone {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20%;
  top: 25em;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

Please help me fix these two problems as this animation is essential to the UX.

Thank you.

Comment: What sets that element to `height: 2621.66px;`? It might help to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate the issue. Stripping it down might even help find the source of the problem.

Comment: I find that div#stickysmartphone has some inline css. Is it added by you or any other library? If it is added by you than you can remove it and try to write proper css in a file and try to add reference for it. https://i.postimg.cc/YSbMSw8J/145.png

Comment: The height aswell as the inline-styles are set ad-hoc by ScrollMagic.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: setting `overflow: hidden` on the inline svg element solved the issue. But I find it very weird that setting `position:fixed` on the containing div changed that. That's IE11 magic I guess.